# Nodejs and WebSockets Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The subprotocol '[object Object]' is invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

So my main webpage example.com is run through cloudflare and has a edge certificate from `Origin -> CF Edge` (origin cert) and an edge certificate `CF Edge -> Client`. I'm bypassing this for my websocket by using a subdomain, `dt.example.com` which uses cloudflare although using this link resolves the origin server address rather than the cloudflare edge server address (which i've found solves some issues for me, or maybe it's counterproductive to use this method?). Anyway, I am using a free ssl certificate for secure websockets -

```js
'use strict';
var https = require('https');
var fs= require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var WebSocket = require('ws');

var server = https.createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/wss/new/certificate.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/wss/new/private.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/wss/new/ca_bundle.crt')
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server});

wss.on('connection', function connection (ws) {
  ws.on('message', function message (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  });
});

server.listen(58443, function listening () {
    const ws = new WebSocket('wss://dt.example.com:58443', {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    });
    ws.on('open', function open () {
        ws.send('Workin baby');
    });
});
```

-and using a websocket client plugin for chrome allows me to connect to the socket, however i cannot on example.com/webpage where the follow code is:

```js
var ws = new window.WebSocket('wss://dt.example.com:58443/', {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});
ws.on('open', function open () {
    ws.send('What\'s crackin?');
});
```

Although in browser (Chrome) when the client script executes it exits with the following error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The subprotocol '[object Object]' is invalid. (on line 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by stumbling across something intriguing in a post [elswhere](https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2).
Essentially I just moved the rejectUnauthorized into the server code and then retried running on the client and it connected to the server :)

Comment: How did you do that?

Answer (score -1):

So there are two ways of doing this i'll list out both of them ,for more information you can visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

**Using W3CWebSocket**

```
var ws= require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;

var client = new W3CWebSocket('wss://dt.example.com:58443/'{
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}, 'echo-protocol');

client.onerror = function() {
    console.log('Connection Error');
};C

client.onopen = function open () {
ws.send('What\'s crackin mate?');
};

client.onclose = function() {
    console.log('echo-protocol Client Closed');
};

client.onmessage = function(e) {
    if (typeof e.data === 'string') {
        console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
    }
};
```

**Using a normal websocket client**

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
        }
    });

});

client.connect('ws://localhost:8080/', 'echo-protocol');
```

Comment: Trying either of these doesn't work on the client as require is not recognised. How would you get around this?

Comment: Nevermind I see that this is moreso a server to server communication app.

Comment: did you install the websocket using npm i --save websocket ?

Comment: into the server directory yes

Comment: although in browser this doesn't work as require isn't recognised as a function, however editing the code works as so
`var client = new window.WebSocket('wss://dt.example.com:58443/');
 ...`

Comment: Yes this should have been added in .js file ,i should have mentioned it .

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by adding corresponding protocol value in front side to the response header in back-end side  with key = "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol".
In your case , you should add a HTTP header with key "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol" and with value "Chat-1.0"

Comment: The original question is tagged JavaScript and node.js, not Java. Answers should be in JavaScript.